# Convert.ToDecimal Format Error

Tags: c#, .net

Got what seems to be a strange issue with Convert.ToDecimal:-

```
decimal percent = 0;
double dr = 0.000015;
Convert.ToDecimal(dr.ToString());
percent = Decimal.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(dr.ToString()), 3);
```

This produces an error "Input string was not in a correct format.".  Changing the dr value slightly, to 0.00015 or even 0.100015 (so, keeping the same amount of DPs) works fine, but not where the first four decimal digits are 0.  I'm a bit stumped on this, it seems rather odd (but it's probably something simple) and I can't see why this would be, maybe, a culture issue?

Edit, for clarification: this isn't my code, I'm fixing an error in someone else's code so I don't know why it was done in that way (possibly the decimal value is actually in a datarow, so the ToString part may be handling null values).

Comment: Look at the result of calling `dr.ToString()`...

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Why are you converting using strings and parsing when you can cast directly?  `percent = Decimal.Round((decimal)dr, 3)`

Comment: You are trying to parse the *default string representation of a double* as the *default string representation of a decimal*. Why would you expect that to work? And what do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`Decimal.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.parse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
var convertedDecimal = Decimal.Parse(dr.ToString(), NumberStyles.Any);
```

`dr.ToString()` would return you a number with Exponential sign like:       `"1.5E-05"`. You have to specify `NumberStyles`. `NumberStyles.Float` would work, but You can use `NumberStyles.Any`.

Or as pointed out in comment by @JoelCoehoorn, you can simply do:

```
 var convertedDecimal = Convert.ToDecimal(dr);
```

as there is no need to convert to string.

Comment: Or, even better, skip converting to a string in the first place.

Comment: Why would you ever use strings and parsing to convert a `double` to a `decimal` when you can explicitly cast?

Comment: This is simplified example code to illustrate the problem without requiring all the data extraction code (esp for debugging) and so that the waters aren't muddied by including too much information

Answer (score -1):

You implied question is:

> How can I convert a double to a string and the parse it to a decimal?

The answer is: you *shouldn't*.  Parsing is an inefficient process and opens up all kinds of potential errors (like the one you've discovered).

You should just cast the value directly:

```
decimal percent = 0;
double dr = 0.000015;
percent = Decimal.Round((decimal)dr, 3);
```

Comment: Thanks, but that isn't my implied question - I'm working on existing code and I'm sure there is a reason why it's done that way